# Twilio voice call: updating call outgoing call does not work

Tags: c#, twilio

I have a simple app which should be able to make an outgoing call. The call should just ask a single question and gather DTML response from user. The tricky part is that I want to know the user's response inside status change callback, when call is completed. I cannot persist call's state in cache, db or any other storage. That's why I thought that I can change the status callback url during the call to include user's response in query parameter. So inside my http handler which handles user's response I have this:

```
CallResource.Update(
    statusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
    statusCallback: statusUrlWithUserResponseinQueryParameter,
    pathSid: id
);
```

And it runs without any exceptions but it seems like it does not do what I want. As a result `statusUrlWithUserResponseinQueryParameter` is not called, url specified during call resource creation is still used. Is it a bug or do I misunderstand something? Are there any other ways to pass user's response to status change callback?

Answer (score 0):

According to this page on ["Updating the Statuscallback of an Active Call"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-the-statuscallback-of-an-active-call&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x), you must update both the URL and the StatusCallbackUrl at the same time:

> To update a StatusCallback on a Call, it is required to set the Url in
> the same statement.

Try updating your code to include a new Url:

```
CallResource.Update(
    url: new Uri(yourNewUriThatHasNewOrTheSameTwiml),
    statusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
    statusCallback: statusUrlWithUserResponseinQueryParameter,
    pathSid: id
);
```

However, I think what you are trying to do is working around how the Gather is intended to work. Typical behavior is to have an app respond to a Gather webhook which will include the digits. The ["Redirect after Gather"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather?code-sample=code-redirect-after-gather&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x) may give you some ideas how to implement what you are trying to accomplish.